# Hide one of background images in multiple background

Tags: css, background-image

I have such a thing:

```
background: url("photo.png") no-repeat scroll center 23px/ 42px 48px,
    url("DeleteAtt.png") no-repeat scroll 81px 3px / 20px 20px #656565;
```

and I need to hide the second background in some situations,
how can I do it?

Comment: Create a new css rule without the second background and use it to override the 2-background rule.

Comment: yeah overriding worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine background property to:

```
background: url("photo.png") no-repeat scroll center 23px/ 42px 48px #656565;
```

Or create a new class and add or remove this class on your element.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture a guess to say that you could do that by changing the background position of the second image.

```
background-position: center 23px, 9999px 3px;
```

Something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Give background size 0 to which image that you want to hide.

For example `background-size: 0, auto;`